# Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Подкорректируйте постановку запятых если нужно.
Но, кажется что в один миг Андрий потерял голову от увлечений...

Answer (score 6):

Запятая ставится перед *что*,на границе частей сложноподчиненного предложения. Слово *кажется* здесь вводным не является.

Answer (score 2):

Но кажется, что в один миг Андрий потерял голову от увлечений...